# Determining whether a system of congruences has a solution

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

Having a system of linear congruences, I'd like to determine if it has a solution. Using simple algorithms that solve such systems is impossible, as the answer may grow exponentially.

One hypothesis I have is that if a system of congruences has no solution, then there are two of them that contradict each other. I have no idea if this holds, if it did that would lead to an easy O(n^2 log n) algo, as checking if a pair of congruences has a solution requires O(log n) time. Nevertheless for this problem I'd rather see something closer to O(n).

We may assume that no moduli exceeds 10^6, especially we can quickly factor them all to begin with. We may even further assume that the *sum* of all moduli doesn't exceed 10^6 (but still, their *product* can be huge).

Comment: This seems like a question for math.stackexchange.com.  Your hypothesis is valid, though: if the congruences are pairwise consistent, then they're mutually consistent.

Comment: What size moduli do you need this to work for?  Are we in the range where factorising those moduli into prime powers is trivially easy (e.g., all moduli smaller than 2**32, say), or does this have to work for much larger moduli?

Comment: Could you provide a short proof for why this hypothesis is true? I've put my question here because the only thing stopping me from solving it in O(n log n) is the fact that storing the partial solutions could exceed available memory - so it's not really a math issue.

Comment: Break it down into prime powers: by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the congruences are mutually consistent iff they're mutually consistent modulo the prime power pieces of the moduli, for each relevant prime, so that reduces to the case where all moduli are powers of a single prime.  And in that case, they're mutually consistent iff they're all consistent with the congruence involving the largest modulus.

Comment: The proof ought to be available online somewhere; the best I've found so far is page 5 of [this PDF](http://www.cs.xu.edu/math/math302/08f/06_CRT.pdf)

Comment: @MarkDickinson here is a counter example (all equations modulo p=17, but that does not really matter): x + y = 2; 2x + y = 3; x = 2. Taking two equations always has a solution but all three don't have a solution.

Comment: Linear congruences as we mean it are of the form: x = a (mod p), so there is only one variable, same in all congruences of the system.

Comment: @Henry: I was assuming a single variable, which was a bit of a case of me jumping to conclusions.  Seems that's what the OP meant, though.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about maths not about programming.

Comment: What do you mean by grow exponentially? The product of the moduli may be huge, but surely the number of bits required to represent it is no more than the total number of bits required to state the problem? Assuming this is the case, the problem should be solvable by any decent multiple-precision arithmetic package - these should have cost to multiply two numbers growing no worse than the square of the number of bits required to represent the answer. (I theory n log n is possible, but n^2 algorithms may be faster for only moderately large n).

Comment: Yes, you're right that if the problem statement could fit in the memory then so should the answer to the system. However, I think there should exist a O(n log n) solution that doesn't go beyond 32 bit integers, as there is an easy, kind of brute-force, O(n^2 log n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, there's a fairly simple way to determine whether the set of congruences has a solution without actually needing to build that solution.  You need to:

1. Reduce each congruence to the form `x = a (mod n)` if necessary; from the comments, it sounds as though you already have this.
2. Factorize each modulus `n` as a product of prime powers: `n = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pk^ek`.
3. Replace each congruence `x = a (mod n)` with a collection of congruences `x = a (mod pi^ei)`, one for each of the `k` prime powers you found in step 2.

And now, by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) it's enough to check compatibility for each prime independently: given any two congruences `x = a (mod p^e)` and `x = b (mod p^f)`, they're compatible if and only if `a = b (mod p^(min(e, f))`.  Having determined compatibility, you can throw out the congruence with smaller modulus without losing any information.

With the right data structures, you can do all this in a single pass through your congruences: for each prime `p` encountered, you'll need to keep track of the biggest exponent `e` found so far, together with the corresponding right-hand side (reduced modulo `p^e` for convenience).  The running time will likely be dominated by the modulus factorizations, though if no modulus exceeds `10^6`, then you can make that step very fast, too, by prebuilding a mapping from each integer in the range `1 .. 10^6` to its smallest prime factor.

---

EDIT: And since this is supposed to be a programming site, here's some (Python 3) code to illustrate the above.  (For Python 2, replace the `range` call with `xrange` for better efficiency.)

```
def prime_power_factorisation(n):
    """Brain-dead factorisation routine, for illustration purposes only."""
    # DO NOT USE FOR LARGE n!
    while n > 1:
        p, pe = next(d for d in range(2, n+1) if n % d == 0), 1
        while n % p == 0:
            n, pe = n // p, pe*p
        yield p, pe


def compatible(old_ppc, new_ppc):
    """Determine whether two prime power congruences (with the same
    prime) are compatible."""
    m, a = old_ppc
    n, b = new_ppc
    return (a - b) % min(m, n) == 0


def are_congruences_solvable(moduli, right_hand_sides):
    """Determine whether the given congruences have a common solution."""

    # prime_power_congruences is a dictionary mapping each prime encountered
    # so far to a pair (prime power modulus, right-hand side).

    prime_power_congruences = {}
    for m, a in zip(moduli, right_hand_sides):
        for p, pe in prime_power_factorisation(m):
            # new prime-power congruence: modulus, rhs
            new_ppc = pe, a % pe
            if p in prime_power_congruences:
                old_ppc = prime_power_congruences[p]
                if not compatible(new_ppc, old_ppc):
                    return False
                # Keep the one with bigger exponent.
                prime_power_congruences[p] = max(new_ppc, old_ppc)
            else:
                prime_power_congruences[p] = new_ppc
    # If we got this far, there are no incompatibilities, and
    # the congruences have a mutual solution.
    return True
```

One final note: in the above, we made use of the fact that the moduli were small, so that computing prime power factorisations wasn't a big deal.  But if you *do* need to do this for much larger moduli (hundreds or thousands of digits), it's still feasible.  You can skip the factorisation step, and instead find a "coprime base" for the collection of moduli: that is, a collection of pairwise relatively prime positive integers such that each modulus appearing in your congruences can be expressed as a product (possibly with repetitions) of elements of that collection.  Now proceed as above, but with reference to that coprime base instead of the set of primes and prime powers.  See [this article](http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/dcba-20040404.pdf) by Daniel Bernstein for an efficient way to compute a coprime base for a set of positive integers. You'd likely end up making *two* passes through your list: one to compute the coprime base, and a second to check the consistency.

Comment: I guess the pass through congruences could possibly be O(m log n) where m is number of congruences, and n biggest moduli, since n can have up to O(log n) distinct prime factors. That's what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you're excluding the cost of the factorisations, `O(m log n)` sounds about right.